# Does polymorphism exist in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, polymorphism

Does polymorphism exist in Ruby? I've read that Ruby does not support polymorphism, and instead it supports method overloading and method overriding. Can someone clarify this for me with an example?

Comment: This really sounds like a plea for someone to do homework for you. You've received  down votes already, for, I suspect, not providing any proof you've done research on the question already. Also, please learn how to format your question, capitalize words like "Ruby", "I", and use proper spacing between sentences and after punctuation. That stuff really does matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Yes, Ruby does support polymorphism.

Consider the case of simple class inheritance where an instance of a derived class "is a" instance of both the child and parent classes:

```
class Parent; end
class Child < Parent; end
o = Child.new
o.is_a?(Child) # => true
o.is_a?(Parent) # => true
```

Note that this example is also valid for included modules:

```
a = Array.new
a.is_a?(Array) # => true
a.is_a?(Enumerable) # => true
```

Of course, Ruby also encourages [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing), which may be the source of confusion regarding the question of properly supporting polymorphism.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby is a highly polymorfic language, in the sense methods don't automatically infer what data type you are passing to them, as long as the object behaves like expected. Example:

```
def concat(a,b)
  a.to_s + b.to_s
end

concat('a', 'bcd')              #=> "abcd"
concat(5, 10)                   #=> "510"
concat([1,2,3], ' is an Array') #=> "[1, 2, 3] is an Array"
```

As long as `a` and `b` respond to `to_s`, the function will output as expected. Check more about Duck Typing for examples.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby doesn't support method overloading. The very *idea* of method overloading doesn't even make sense in a dynamically typed language.

Ruby *does* support ad-hoc polymorphism, just like pretty much every object-oriented language on the planet.